# getResources + &tvFilters + checkbox TV

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

There is a TV assigned to a template:

### Input Options

```
Input Type: Check Box
Input Option Values: Category1||Category2||Category3||Category4
Allow Blank: No
```

### Output Options

```
Output Type: Delimeter
Delimiter: ,
```

For example:

A getResources call lists the pages with "Category1" checked on the Category1 page - &tvFilters=`Category1` used. A getResources call lists the pages with "Category2" checked on the Category2 page - &tvFilters=`Category2` used. Etc. Everything is O.K. and as expected.

But if two or more checkboxes are checked on a page, the page disappears from both the Category1 and Category2 pages.

What can be done?

Comment: How about `&tvFilters=\`NameOfYourTv==Category2\`` ?

Answer (score 3):

If more than one tag has been entered you need to add a % wildcard:

```
&tvFilters=`NameOfYourTv==%Category1%`
```